# Evaluating the same operations on several files

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I corrected my code but still, I can't plot my data...It was working well but when I added a 4th or 5th files...it doesn't work...I don't understande why.. even if I corrected the last line as follow

```
Show[func /@ {{file1, Blue}, {file2, Orange}, {file3, Purple}}, 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

to `Show[func /@ {{file1, Blue}, {file2, Orange}, {file3, Purple},{file4, Black}},  PlotRange -> All]`

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
(*Take all the file in the main folder where the notebook is saved*)

allFiles = FileNames["*.dat", NotebookDirectory[]];

(*function who will be used to transform the data*)

func[{file_String /; FileExistsQ[file], plotStyle_}] := 
 Module[{data, dataT, formatted}, data = Import[file, "Table"];
  dataT = Transpose[data];
  dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]], dataT[[3]], dataT[[4]]};
  data = Transpose[dataT];
  formatted = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#4, #3]} & @@@ data;
  ErrorListPlot[{formatted}, PlotStyle -> plotStyle, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{FileBaseName[file]}], {Right, Top}]]]

(*Plot a combine graph of the multiple data file*)

Show[func /@ {{file1, Blue}, {file2, Orange}, {file3, Purple}}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Lookup `Table`.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't understand how to use Table on each line on my code...

Comment: More or less `Show @ Table[ ..., {file, {file1, file2, file3}}]`.

Comment: So I use the following line to import all my file, but then how to use Table to for example do the transpose of each file ? 

 SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
allFiles = FileNames["*.dat", NotebookDirectory[]];

data = Import[#] & /@ files;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a function that takes a filename and returns a plot. It is good practice to put all variables you use into a local `Module`

```
func[file_String /; FileExistsQ[file]] := Module[
  {
   data, dataT, formatted
   },
  data = Import[file, "Table"];
  dataT = Transpose[data];
  dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]], dataT[[3]], dataT[[4]]};
  data = Transpose[dataT];
  formatted = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#4, #3]} & @@@ data;
  ErrorListPlot[{formatted}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{FileBaseName[file]}], {0.7, 0.8}]]
  ]
```

Now, you can simply do

```
func /@ {file1, file2, file3}
```

and you get a list of graphics.

## Edit

If you want to define the styling for each file, you can include this in the function

```
func[{file_String /; FileExistsQ[file], plotStyle_}] := Module[
  {
   data, dataT, formatted
   },
  data = Import[file, "Table"];
  dataT = Transpose[data];
  dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]], dataT[[3]], dataT[[4]]};
  data = Transpose[dataT];
  formatted = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#4, #3]} & @@@ data;
  ErrorListPlot[{formatted}, PlotStyle -> plotStyle, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{FileBaseName[file]}], {0.7, 0.8}]]
  ]
```

and then call

```
func /@ {{file1, Red}, {file2, Green}, {file3, Blue}}
```

Comment: Thank  and thanks for the advise, I will try to learn better how to use it.

Comment: If I want to plot them in different color, how  can I do that using Colorfunction instead of PlotStyle ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. `ErrorListPlot` is basically a `ListPlot`, but the `ColorFunction` does only work for list-plots that have `Joined -> True` which makes absolutely no sense for an error plot.

Comment: Ok, I used Show[func /@ files, PlotRange -> All] to generate a combine graph. how can I generate differente colore for each file in my combine file ?

Comment: Please see my edit in the answer.

Comment: thanks, it works. But When I want to add a 4th file, by changing 
func /@ {{file1, Red}, {file2, Green}, {file3, Blue}} to func /@ {{file1, Red}, {file2, Green}, {file3, Blue}, {file4, Blue}} , it doesn't work...I get this error message "Skeleton is not a graphics directive." and "Ignoring invalid graphics directive "Hue[Skeleton[3]]". What have I done wrong ?and I can see only the 3rd first graph...